# WP8 Save file with http request in Background task when the app closes

Tags: windows-phone-8, background, save, http-request, close-application

I would like to store data in the dropbox via http request when the app closes. The time of 10 seconds in the Application_Closing function are not enough. Is there a background task that runs longer after closing the app?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Did you check out the Background file transfer Agent? You can find a detailed description on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), note that there are some restrictions to file size depending onto the network connection.